# AngularJS. Добавление примитива или массива в Json от условия

Tags: json, angularjs

Есть некий `json` объект, который содержит параметр `value`. Этот параметр принимает значение (допустим 2) моделей из `input`. Есть также чекбокс, который устанавливает тип значения инпутов. Это может быть примитив(например число или стринг) или массив (чисел или стрингов).

[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview)

работает для примитивов. Если ввести в первый инпут значение 1,2,3 а во второй 4,5,6 json примет вид:

```
 "value": [
        "1,2,3",
        "4,5,6"
      ]
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатом чекбоксе, значения модели воспринимались как массив элементов и json имел вид:

```
 "value": [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6]
      ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JS:

```
$scope.args = [{
    arg_name: '',
    is_array: false, // Добавим новый параметр для чекбокса
    value:[]
}];

$scope.function = {
  type: 0,
  array_type: 0,
  args : $scope.args
};

// Введем новую переменную, которая будет хранить измененный массив function 
$scope.res_function = null;

// Следим за любыми изменениями в function
$scope.$watch('function', function(_data) {
  // Копируем исходный массив
  $scope.res_function = angular.copy(_data);
  // В цикле проходим по все элементам args
  for (var i = 0; i < _data.args.length; i++) {
    // Если у элемента is_array будет true
    if (_data.args[i].is_array) {
      // В цикле пройдем по всем элементам value исходного массива
      for (var j = 0; j < _data.args[i].value.length; j++) {
        // И запишем в копию массива их же, но разделенные по запятой
        $scope.res_function.args[i].value[j] = _data.args[i].value[j].split(',');
        // Тут вам нужно будет добавить проверку на то, что находится в _data.args[i].value[j], так как split может вызвать ошибку
      }
    }
  };
}, true);
```

В HTML:

Нужно добавить `ng-model="args[0].is_array"` к чекбоксу

И результат теперь выводим так:

```
<pre>{{res_function | json}}</pre>
```

[Рабочий пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tU2W9wK8XRcwNqVzVPK?p=preview)